# jquery condition remove disable

Tags: jquery

I have a class that has the value of total

```
<span class="price-value">0</span>
```

and a class of a radio button

```
class="radio-livraison element-radio-input" disabled="disabled"
```

is is possible to disable the radio button and enable it only if total is more than 28; 
example you can't check the radio button if span price-value is less than 28

```
<script>
  if ($('.ezfc-price-value') > 24){
    $('.ly-radio-livraison').removeAttr("disabled");
  }
</script>
```

but I get error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I have jQuery and Bootstrap on my template before the code.

Comment: try `jQuery('.ezfc-price-value') `?

Comment: Do you have jquery referenced and are you seeing it in your source (in developer tools)?

Comment: Please update your post with the result of `console.log(jQuery)` and `console.log($)`.

Comment: console.log(jQuery)  ->  ƒ (a,b){return new n.fn.init(a,b)} ; console.log($)-> undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    if (parseInt$('.ezfc-price-value').text()) > 24){
      $('.ly-radio-livraison').prop("disabled", false);
    }
</script>
```

You need to compare the text inside that element, not the element itself.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

demo: http://jsbin.com/toguruzure/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){
$(".price-value").change(function(){
 $('.radio-livraison').prop("disabled", !(parseInt($('.price-value').text()) > 28));
});

$("#total").on('input', function(){
  $(".price-value").text($(this).val()).change();
});
```

})